# containers.Map doesn't work with numeric keys

Tags: matlab

I have the following problem with a containers.Map object in Matlab.
Creating a simple object with numeric keys and values:

```
m = containers.Map(1:3,2:4);
>> m(1)
ans =
 2
```

Works as expected, but

```
>> m(1:2)
Error using containers.Map/subsref
Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.
```

gives me an error that I don't expect and don't understand, because the key type is obviously correct.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685364/matlab-specified-value-type-does-not-match-the-type-expected-for-this-container) may point you down the right path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: Specified value type does not match the type expected for this container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685364/matlab-specified-value-type-does-not-match-the-type-expected-for-this-container)

Answer (score 2):

The [containers.Map](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html)

default construction uses `kType` determined by the data types of keys in `keySet`, ( here  `double` ) .

`containers.Map` cannot have `KeyType` anything thing other than:

`'char', 'double', 'single', 'int32', 'uint32', 'int64', or 'uint64'.`

In your example `1:2` is matrix of 1x2 so cannot be used as key.

Comment: `1:2` is also of type double, isn't it?

Comment: @user1618022 matrix of double. Unfortunately vectorization won't work here.

Answer (score 1):

When calling your container with

```
m(1:2)
```

you are supplying a 1x2 matrix which is not allowed as a key in containers.map. Matlab does not allow to vectorize the retrieval of multiple values based on multiple keys in the map class.

If your code relies heavily on the map class and frequently needs to extract multiple keys, you might want to reconsider using the map class.

See the section "Avoid using containers.map" in the book [Accelerating Matlab Performance](https://books.google.de/books?id=tXPOBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Yair Altman.